# Pass variable from python script to C program(command line argument)

Tags: python, c, wxpython, subprocess, wxwidgets

I am here with a issue that : I have a GUI (wxpython), it has spinctrl, the output of spinctrl must be sent to c file, which accept command line argument, so whenever i execute c file using subprocess  as it accepts value from GUI the spinctrl value must be sent to it instead of manual typing.

My code is:

```
      ps = "password" 
      var1 = self.sc1.Getvalue()
      var2 = self.sc2.Getvalue()
      subprocess.call(['echo xsxsxs | sudo "./license.exe"', str(ps), str(var1), str(var2)],shell = True)
```

whenever i run this script it doesnot show output/error :(

if i remove echo xsxsxs| sudo from the line 4 and then execute then it show error: "you must be root user","Invalid password", "segmentation fault".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use `shell=True` to `subprocess.Popen` (or one of the convenience wrappers), you should pass a string exactly the way you would type it in your shell, not a `list`.

from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

Comment: I didnot understand your concept. can you please clarify it?

Comment: Since your last argument is `shell=True`, you should build the string for the entire command yourself: `cmd = 'echo xsxsxs | sudo "./license.exe" {} {} {}'.format(ps, var1, var2)` then `subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)`